# install red5 server on an ubuntu12.04 server

Tags: java, red5

I've been struggling with this during 2 weeks without get it done.

I'm building a website where the users will have to record a video and post it as there cv and for this I need a RTMP server.

I picked RED5 cause it is free. This is the first time I'm doing this, so I started to read some tutorials about how to install red5 server. But most of them are on a version of Ubuntu  older than the 12.04.

When I type the command to install java `apt-get install java-package` the server return ***unable to locate package java-package***. And I need to install java ant and subversion before installing the red5 server.

I'm using putty on windows seven to get access to my server.

Answer (score 2):

***java-package*** is not a package in the repositories and you probably already have Java installed in your system (type `java -version` to test that).

Instead of following some outdated tutorials on the internet you should have a look at already packed packages for your system, [RED5 is available](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/red5-server) and packed for 12.04, so it will be easier for you to install it with `apt`.

To install RED5 in Ubuntu the only thing you need to do is to run `sudo apt-get install red5-server` in a terminal.

After install your server should be up and running, you can check it's status with `sudo service red5-server status` and access it via your browser at the address `localhost:5080`

[image]

This will install all the necessary packages and dependencies required to run RED5. After you do that the server will be available and running at `http://localhost:5080`.

Comment: I've just try your command. It's like i've come to install red5 properly. but when I open the server (my server name/5080) there is a display 404 in the center of the page. And I can't get access to the install page.

Comment: or  maybe I just have to start the server my self? What is the command for that? I'try [sh red5.sh] but it's not working. I got the following error: sh: 0: Can't open red5.sh

Comment: I would say that the installation would leave you with and service that you can stop/start/status check, so try `sudo service red5-server status`.

Comment: I have tested this right now, its flawless, try checking the status of the server with the command above and check your open ports with  `sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i6`.

Comment: The picture on the post is the actual server running immediately after install on a test vbox.

Comment: I'm having the same result than you when I type sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i6 but stiil not making it... If I were able to post image I may show you my display

Comment: Is this a remote server? maybe the issue is not that the server is not running but you cannot reach it properly because of your network? Do you have physical access to the machine?

Comment: Nope! And yes it's a remote server. I'm using putty to get access to it. And yes ly network is not that good. But the client finaly ask someone else to do the job. Gesss I hav now to learn more about server and RTM protocols

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno Pereira at least you teach that I don't need to install java ant and subversion before installing red5. But I'll apriciate if you give more links where I could learn all those stuffs about RTMP and how to configure them

Answer (score 0):

hey guise here is a follow up ok so I was able to reproduce same issue here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz7lb.png)

"HTTP Status 404 - /vod/index.html

type Status report

message /vod/index.html

description The requested resource (/vod/index.html) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35"

Just point out I recently did a fresh Install of "ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64" and then proceded to install "red5-server" Im able to open the localhost:5080 page but can not access the /demos or /installer as smart-ba describes...

heres my bash history since start up of fresh install

```
 1  sudo apt-get clean
 2  sudo apt-get update
 3  sudo apt-get upgrade
 4  java -version
 5  sudo apt-get install red5-server
 6  java -version
 7  sudo service red5-server status
 8  sudo apt-get clean
 9  sudo apt-get update
10  sudo apt-get upgrade
11  java -version
12  sudo service red5-server status
13  sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i6
14  sudo ./red5-server stop
15  cd /etc/init.d/
16  sudo ./red5-server stop
17  sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i6
18  sudo ./red5-server start
19  sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i6
20  sudo ./red5-server restart
21  history
```

after re-evaluation of this install I've noticed that on the localhost:5080 page under the HTTP Status 404 issue it has the following statement.

" "red5-server" package doesn't contains /demos or /installer webapps. Please note that /installer and /demos webapps are for demonstration purpose only and should never be installed on a public red5 server (no security at all in those applications)."

so just pointing out that this was properly installed as i just have done myself even tho u get the 404 error thats ok.

Answer (score 0):

To install demo and installer use the below command

```
wget http://www.red5.org/downloads/red5/1_0/red5-1.0.0-RC1.tar.gz
tar xvzf red5-*.tar.gz
cd red5-*
cp -R webapps/root/demos /var/lib/red5/webapps/root/demos
cp -R webapps/installer /var/lib/red5/webapps/installer
find /var/lib/red5/webapps/ -type d -exec chown _red5 {} \;
cd ..
rm -rf red5-*
```